# I faced an issue with start UI on Ubuntu 22.04 after login

Tags: gnome, 22.04, login, gui

Until now everything has worked well.But today when I tried to login happend next one.

I boot my Ubuntu and see login screen as usual.
I fill login and password fields as usual
After that system stucks and I see blue screen
After a few afforts I logged in, but after system reboot I got sameissue again.

If a switch from Ubuntu UI to Gnome default UI (on login screen), I get access to the system, there is no any problems.

Does anyone have any ideas?